# How do I prevent Other apps to format my NFC cards

Tags: android, nfc

I would like to know if there is a way by which i can prevent other NFC Apps to read the NFC tags or prevent them to format my tag. However i cannot lock the NFC tag because the information keeps changing in my TAG.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. If you can not lock the NFC tag, then by definition it is not locked and anybody can write on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use secured tag as desfire cards.

This kind of card can be secured by keys.

So only app have keys could read/write/format tag.

Comment: Even simpler NFC chips like the NTAG210 support password protection. [link](http://www.nxp.com/products/identification_and_security/smart_label_and_tag_ics/ntag/series/NTAG210_NTAG212.html)